# How to calculate the color based on the percentage?

Tags: android, colors

`MAX_PROGRESS` is 100,this can be calculated based on progress color,vut I now need to calculate `progress` by color,is there such an algorithm?

```
private int calculateColor(int progress) {
        float unit = (float) progress / MAX_PROGRESS;
        if (unit < 0) {
            unit += 1;
        }

        if (unit <= 0) {
            return mGradientColors[0];
        }
        if (unit >= 1) {
            return mGradientColors[mGradientColors.length - 1];
        }

        float p = unit * (mGradientColors.length - 1);
        int i = (int) p;
        p -= i;

        int c0 = mGradientColors[i];
        int c1 = mGradientColors[i + 1];
        int a = ave(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), p);
        int r = ave(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), p);
        int g = ave(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), p);
        int b = ave(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), p);

        return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
    }
```

Comment: Don't think so.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I'm doing a palette seekbar,i need to scroll to the corresponding progress according to the color.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest pre-calculating the colors and put them in a `Map<int, int>` where the key is the color value represented as an int and the value is the progress in percent. To get the percentage for a given color you can use `get(color)`.

Comment: Agreed. That should do